# Networking app not running on Hololens emulator

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

NetworkingHololens in the application name and I'm trying to use the SharingService to manipulate a cube over the network.

When I run other apps(without the networking capability), it runs fine on the HoloLens emulator, but when I run this or any other networking app, the following error shows up after the "Made with Unity", and just becomes black.

***Updated Logs***

```
Direct3D:

Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]

Renderer: Microsoft RemoteFX Graphics Device - WDDM (ID=0x2c1)

Vendor:   Microsoft

VRAM:     639 MB

Initialize engine version: 2017.1.1f1 (5d30cf096e79)

'Cube HoloLens Networking.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\CubeHoloLensNetworkingVS.Debug_x86.Abhijit\UnityEngineProxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Cube HoloLens Networking.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\CubeHoloLensNetworkingVS.Debug_x86.Abhijit\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Cube HoloLens Networking.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\CubeHoloLensNetworkingVS.Debug_x86.Abhijit\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The following GlobalManagers were stripped from the build (Either because they're not used or not supported on this platform):
  NetworkManager
  MasterServerInterface
  ClusterInputManager
  CrashReportManager

If your machine has multiple graphics adapters, Unity may have created a WindowContext on the wrong adapter. If you experience a black screen when playing, please restart the Editor.

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/VR/VRDevice.cpp Line: 219)


d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x1 mode 2 size 4194304) [0x887A0005]

d3d11: attempt to lock null buffer

Assertion failed on expression: 'm_Buffer != NULL'

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/BufferD3D11.cpp Line: 174)


The program '[740] Cube HoloLens Networking.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I was hoping anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: I'm just working on a app that runs in the emulator using the Sharing Service. Please, check if the *Sharing Service* capabilities are checked. In the Sharing Service, you can check if the HoloLens emulator is connected or not.

Comment: You mean the internet capabilities? Yes, it is checked.It works on the HoloLens (the anchor text showing its connected), but the app crashes with the above log when I run on the Emulator.

Comment: I mean that you need to 'Enable the sharing service' in the project setting and check the `Internet Client Server` and `Private Network Client Server` in the `UWP Capabilities`. And, of course, the sharing service must be accessible for the Hololens Emulator.

Comment: I was previously using the older Holotoolkit but I just updated to the 2017.2 MixedReality Toolkit, updated to Unity 2017.1. Enabled them as you said. but the app still crashes. Updated the question with the new crash logs.